# Can you 'pop' a magnetic bottle of plasma with a laser?

Tags: laser, plasma-physics

A [LightCraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightcraft) works by using a laser to superheat air into plasma so that it violently expands and provides thrust to a remove object.

If there was a ball of plasma, sitting in the vacuum of space in a magnetic bottle, would it be feasible to 'pop' the magnetic bottle by shining a laser onto a specific point on the plasma ball, giving it enough energy to overcome the magnetic force?

I'm asking to judge the validity of a tactic in science-fiction space combat - bouncing plasma weapons fire back at the attacker with lasers. (I wasn't sure if this belongs in here or in World-Building.)